# Applying a Box Model to the following HTML

Tags: css

so I'm relativity new to coding and am still in the early stages of learning.

Im currently working through CSS but am struggling with applying a box model to the following code.

Im trying to get it to appear like this
[Box Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Vyig.png)

Can anyone help me out?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Logans Dinner</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>Welcome to Logans Dinner</header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href='/Menu.html'>Menu</a></li>
        <li><a href='/About.html'>About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href='/Contact.html'>Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    </header>
  <section>
    <p>Our Menu</p>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Food</th>
         <th>Description</th>
         <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
       <tr>
        <td>Burger</td>
        <td>1/2 lb Angus Beef</td>
        <td>$10.99</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it's not clear what you want...

Comment: Box Model is just css convention of ```margin-border-padding-width/height```. Can you please add a diagram or sketch for what you need as output

Comment: I added an Image of what Im trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know if this help you or at least give you an idea, and based on that you can work on what you really want. I added here the same code that you provided and modified adding a box in the part that you have saying "Our menu". Because it is not clear what you want to do, try this and I hope this helps you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Logans Dinner</title>

    <style>
    /* added a div to your code with the CSS code in order to configure */
      div {
          background-color: lightblue;
          width: 300px;
          border: 5px solid red;
          padding: 20px;
          margin: 2px;
      }

      table, th, td {
          border: 2px solid black;
          border-collapse: collapse;
      }
      th, td {
          padding: 15px;
      }
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <header>Welcome to Logans Dinner</header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href='/Menu.html'>Menu</a></li>
        <li><a href='/About.html'>About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href='/Contact.html'>Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    </header>
  <section>

  <div> 
      <p>Our Menu</p>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Food</th>
           <th>Description</th>
           <th>Price</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
         <tr>
          <td>Burger</td>
          <td>1/2 lb Angus Beef</td>
          <td>$10.99</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. To clarify what I am trying to do is have the nav section off to the left side in its own box and have the section and table centered.

Comment: That is good to know I was able to help. Please use the check mark icon to accept this answer. I also provided and answer to your question "
Tuning up the Box Model layout" and give you an example that try to match what you were looking for, in addition I added some CSS feature that could be useful for you.